# flutte app run in background only if device is connected to usb charger

Tags: flutter

I try to validate simple task => persiste the vibration when device is horizontal (user sitdown)
Currently it's work when the screen is off only if device is connected to the laptop or usb charger. I try workmanager and android_alarm_manager but I have same issue. I'm doing something wrong ? or it's Impossible ?

Here is a simple reproduce code to test timer and vibration in background when device is connected and not connected.

```
import 'package:android_alarm_manager/android_alarm_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vibration/vibration.dart';
import 'dart:async';
main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Timer _timer;
  test_vibration() {
    _timer= Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      Vibration.vibrate();
    });

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
      AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), 0, test_vibration());
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

here is more complet example with accelerometer

```
import 'package:sensors/sensors.dart';
import 'package:android_alarm_manager/android_alarm_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vibration/vibration.dart';
import 'dart:async';
main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 
List<double> _accelerometerValues;

List<StreamSubscription<dynamic>> _streamSubscriptions =
<StreamSubscription<dynamic>>[];


test_vibration() {

  _streamSubscriptions.add(accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event) {    // Stream accelerometre
      _accelerometerValues = <double>[event.y];  read accelerometer y
    

      if (event.y>6.0||event.y<-6.0){ //device vertical

      }else{ // device horizontal

        Vibration.vibrate();

      }
  }));
}



  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    _streamSubscriptions.add(accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event) {
      setState(() {
        _accelerometerValues = <double>[event.y];
      });

      AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), 0, test_vibration());

    }));
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solution I found :
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />`